# "cannot execute binary file" when using su

Tags: bash, permission, monterey

The following works.

```
$ ls -d /tmp
/tmp@
```

But if I try to execute it with `su` it doesn't work.

```
$ su otheruser ls -d /tmp
Password:
/bin/ls: /bin/ls: cannot execute binary file
```

Then, if I become the user, it works again.

```
$ su - otheruser
Password:

The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.
$ ls -d /tmp
/tmp@
```

Any idea what's happening here?  I'm running Monterey on an Intel Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the wrong syntax for running a command with `su`. The syntax you're using would work with `sudo`, but `su` works differently. To run a command with `su`, use the `-c` option with the entire command as a single string:

```
su otheruser -c 'ls -d /tmp'
```

(The arguments after the username are actually passed to the other user's login shell as arguments, but pretty much all shells understand `-c` as meaning "here's a command string to run".)

Alternately, you could do pretty much the same thing with `sudo`:

```
sudo -u otheruser ls -d /tmp
```

Note that `su` will ask for the password of the account you're switching *to*, while `sudo` will ask for the password of the account you're switching *from* (and also verify that you're authorized to run that command as that other user in the /etc/sudoers file).

Comment: I guess I've used `sudo` in favour of `su` for so long I've forgotten the syntax.  Thanks for your answer.  I also didn't know you could `sudo` to a non-root user.  I think I will do that from now on instead of `su`.